# Grails - NullPointerException occured when processing request POST

Tags: grails, groovy, hql

I'm building a grails application and getting an error that I really cannot understand here.

So, I'm using ajax calls and the dropdowns send values to the controller.
The controller is throwing an error :

```
NullPointerException occured when processing request POST
```

Code #1

```
    def com = Com.executeQuery("select p.date_hour, (sum(p.atc_visits)*100), 
case when (sum(atc_visits_ly)) IN (0,null) THEN 0 ELSE (((sum(atc_visits))/(sum(atc_visits_ly)) - 1)*100*100) END as yoy,
 case when (sum(atc_visits_lw)) IN (0,null) THEN 0 ELSE (((sum(atc_visits))/(sum(atc_visits_lw)) - 1)*100*100) END as wow, 
p.mv, p.browser, p.department, p.platform, p.device, p.time_period from Com p where p.department = ? and p.time_period = ? group by p.date_hour order by col_0_0_ asc ",[params.department, params.time_period])
                    render com as JSON
```

Code #2

```
    def com = Com.executeQuery("select p.date_hour, (sum(p.atc_visits)*100), 
case when (sum(atc_visits_ly)) IN (0,null) THEN 0 ELSE (((sum(atc_visits))/(sum(atc_visits_ly)) - 1)*100*100) END as yoy, 
case when (atc_visits_lw) IN (0,null) THEN 0 ELSE ((atc_visits/atc_visits_lw - 1)*100*100) END as wow, p.mv, p.browser, p.department, p.platform, p.device, p.time_period from Com p where p.department = ? and p.time_period = ? group by p.date_hour order by col_0_0_ asc ",[params.department, params.time_period])
                    render com as JSON
```

In code #2, the error goes away, whereas in code #1 the error comes, this I realized while debugging.
The only difference is that in code #2, I have changed `sum(atc_visits_lw)` to `atc_visits_lw`. But this aggregation has to be done, it's important in this case.
I also changed - `atc_visits -> sum(atc_visits)` but this throws no error.
**Error is only because of :  `sum(atc_visits_lw)` **

I looked up the error and there was nothing similar to what I am facing here.
What could I possibly be doing wrong here? How can I resolve this issue?

I ran the same query in sql and checked in excel with the backend, but the values for `atc_visits_lw` is there everywhere

All feedback is highly appreciated

Comment: @AnIshA Next time when proposing an edit, please address all the issues a question may have and not just the low-hanging fruit.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very simple problem and one that was not in the controller neither the index.

In my domain class, I had not defined the variable **"marketing_lw"** only.
A very big blunder from my side.

After defining the variable, it worked perfectly.